# I'm getting the error "TypeError: 'int' object doesn't support item assignment" in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
T=int(input())
A,B=[0]*T
for i in range(T):
    A[i],B[i]=[int(n) for n in input().split()]
for j in range(T):
    print(A[j]+B[j])
```

In this, I'm getting the error:

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                                                                         
    A[i],B[i]=[int(n) for n in input().split()]                                                                                                                                               
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Where am I going wrong?
Edit: Made the code

```
A=B=[0]*T
```

when I try the output for 3+4, the answer shown is 8. :( It's basically assigning the second value to both A[i] and B[i].

The question is: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW001

Comment: What are you trying to do please explain yourself.

Comment: echo what @ikibir said, including the input values as well.

Comment: Your code means `A[0] = something` where the value of `A` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
A,B=[0]*T
```

This **does not** make `A` and `B` each be separate lists with `T` copies of `0`. It makes a **single** list, and then tries to assign *each element of that list* to the variables `A` and `B` respectively - i.e. it can only work when `T` is exactly 2.

When you don't get an error there, `A` and `B` are both equal to `0` - an integer, not a list. Thus, later, `A[i]` cannot work because you are indexing into a non-list.

Comment: OP is probably looking for the syntax `A = B = [0] * T` here…

Comment: I think there are several more logical errors here, but it's not clear what OP wants the program to do.

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know that. I'm new to Python. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: i wont support A = B = [0] * T , this is because on assigning things to the list either of the variables (A or B) holds later on, would over write what the other holds. this is because of the mutability of list. A[0]=99 changes B[0]=99